# i have issues with while rendering dynamic data for templates

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

## Code below models

```
class Events(models.Model):
    event_author=models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    event_title=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    event_title_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=False)
    event_description=models.TextField(blank = True)
    event_image_description = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)
    event_release_date = models.DateField(null="false")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.event_title

    def publish(self):
        self.event_release_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

## views

```
def Event(request):
    events=Events.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('event_title')
    return render(request, 'polls/events.html', {})
```

## templates

```
<p>Events page </p>
{{ events }}
```

## Error

```
FieldError at /events
Cannot resolve keyword 'published_date' into field. Choices are: event_author, event_description, event_image_description, event_release_date, event_title, event_title_image, id
```

while I am running a server I got an error like filed error please help out of this i am new django.

Comment: Which field do you want to display?

Comment: You're trying to render a field that don't exist

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're filtering on a field which not included on your model.

```py
events=Events.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('event_title')
```

as I can see, your published_date is correspond to field `event_release_date` on your model, so it supposed to be like this:

```py
events=Events.objects.filter(event_release_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('event_title')
```